# Calculating an Estimate of Uncompressed PST/OST/mail containers

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I'm writing a program that tries to estimate "exploded" size of all logical files. The issue being there are (possibly) compressed containers like .ZIP, .PST/.OST, etc.

I was wondering for the best way to approach mail containers if we were to "explode" them (extract all the contents within) and estimate the size all the uncompressed contents would be (.MSG files, etc).

It would be nice to avoid having to extract them into a TMP directory, but if that's the only way it can be done then so be it.

Answer (score 0):

Zip files contain the size of the original files.. so something like dotnetzip library could help you with those files.

Comment: Indeed. DotNetZip has been a lifesaver in general.